# Problema al insertar nuevos valores y nueva sentencia sql

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

Estoy haciendo un formulario y todo esta bien hasta que quise agregar otra sentencia sql la cual era de insert y me aparecio este error al querer agregar mas informacion:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Estoy realizando basicamente un CRUD con php, mysql y JS.Cuando estube haciendo el llenado de datos para una tabla unicamnete el codigo corria bien, pero cuando quise agregar otra sentencia sql para llenar otra tabla ya me marca esos errores.Este es el codigo que si funcionaba bien antes de agregar la nueva sentencia:

Este es de una clase

```
 public function insert_paciente($nombrePac,$apellidoP,$apellidoM,$edad,$sexo,$ocupacion,$telefono,$calleNum,$colonia,$cp,$ciudad){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO paciente (idPaciente, nombrePac, apellidoP, apellidoM, edad, Sexo_idSexo, Ocupacion_idOcupacion, telefono, calleNumero, colonia, cp, ciudad, fecha_crea, fecha_modi) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(),null)";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$nombrePac);
    $sql->bindValue(2,$apellidoP);
    $sql->bindValue(3,$apellidoM);
    $sql->bindValue(4,$edad);
    $sql->bindValue(5,$sexo);
    $sql->bindValue(6,$ocupacion);
    $sql->bindValue(7,$telefono);
    $sql->bindValue(8,$calleNum);
    $sql->bindValue(9,$colonia);
    $sql->bindValue(10,$cp);
    $sql->bindValue(11,$ciudad);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

//Este codigo es de otra clase diferente

  case "guardaryeditar":
     $datos = $paciente->get_paciente_x_id($_POST["idPaciente"]);
     if(empty($_POST["idPaciente"])){ //Si "idPaciente" esta vacio o no tiene alguna informacion
        if(is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) == 0){ //Si la variable "datos" no me trajo ningun registro o ningun array, se realiza el insert
           $paciente->insert_paciente($_POST["nombrePac"],$_POST["apellidoP"],$_POST["apellidoM"],$_POST["edad"],
           $_POST["Sexo_idSexo"],$_POST["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"],$_POST["telefono"],$_POST["calleNumero"],$_POST["colonia"],
           $_POST["cp"],$_POST["ciudad"]); //La variable "paciente" llama a la funcion insert_paciente
        }
     }else{
        $paciente->update_paciente($_POST["idPaciente"], $_POST["nombrePac"], $_POST["apellidoP"], $_POST["apellidoM"],
        $_POST["edad"], $_POST["Sexo_idSexo"], $_POST["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"], $_POST["telefono"], $_POST["calleNumero"],
        $_POST["colonia"], $_POST["cp"], $_POST["ciudad"]);
     }
  break;
```

Ahora este es el codigo ya con las midificaciones y con el que me marca error

```
 public function insert_paciente($nombrePac,$apellidoP,$apellidoM,$edad,$sexo,$ocupacion,$telefono,$calleNum,$colonia,$cp,$ciudad,
$localizacion,$sintomas){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql = "INSERT INTO paciente (idPaciente, nombrePac, apellidoP, apellidoM, edad, Sexo_idSexo, Ocupacion_idOcupacion, telefono, calleNumero, colonia, cp, ciudad, fecha_crea, fecha_modi) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(),null)";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO dolor (idDolor, Localizacion_idLocalizacion, sintomas) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)";
    $sql = $conectar->prepare($sql);
    $sql->bindValue(1,$nombrePac);
    $sql->bindValue(2,$apellidoP);
    $sql->bindValue(3,$apellidoM);
    $sql->bindValue(4,$edad);
    $sql->bindValue(5,$sexo);
    $sql->bindValue(6,$ocupacion);
    $sql->bindValue(7,$telefono);
    $sql->bindValue(8,$calleNum);
    $sql->bindValue(9,$colonia);
    $sql->bindValue(10,$cp);
    $sql->bindValue(11,$ciudad);
    $sql->bindValue(12,$localizacion);
    $sql->bindValue(13,$sintomas);
    $sql->execute();
    return $resultado = $sql->fetchAll();
}

case "guardaryeditar":
     $datos = $paciente->get_paciente_x_id($_POST["idPaciente"]);
     if(empty($_POST["idPaciente"])){ //Si "idPaciente" esta vacio o no tiene alguna informacion
        if(is_array($datos) == true and count($datos) == 0){ //Si la variable "datos" no me trajo ningun registro o ningun array, se realiza el insert
           $paciente->insert_paciente($_POST["nombrePac"],$_POST["apellidoP"],$_POST["apellidoM"],$_POST["edad"],
           $_POST["Sexo_idSexo"],$_POST["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"],$_POST["telefono"],$_POST["calleNumero"],$_POST["colonia"],
           $_POST["cp"],$_POST["ciudad"], $_POST["Localizacion_idLocalizacion"], $_POST["sintomas"]); //La variable "paciente" llama a la funcion insert_paciente
        }
     }else{
        $paciente->update_paciente($_POST["idPaciente"], $_POST["nombrePac"], $_POST["apellidoP"], $_POST["apellidoM"],
        $_POST["edad"], $_POST["Sexo_idSexo"], $_POST["Ocupacion_idOcupacion"], $_POST["telefono"], $_POST["calleNumero"],
        $_POST["colonia"], $_POST["cp"], $_POST["ciudad"]);
     }
  break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error que te está dando es porque tu has "bindeado" 13 parámetros, y la variable $sql en la que los estás "bindeando" solo espera 2.

Si te fijas estás utilizando la misma variable $sql para hacer las 2 queries, así que la segunda sobrescribe la primera. Te recomendaría que si tienes que hacer 2 quieres las hagas por separado.

Entonces tu función insertar paciente quedaría así:

```
public function insert_paciente($nombrePac,$apellidoP,$apellidoM,$edad,$sexo,$ocupacion,$telefono,$calleNum,$colonia,$cp,$ciudad,
$localizacion,$sintomas){ 
    $conectar = parent::conexion();
    parent::set_names();
    $sql_paciente = "INSERT INTO paciente (idPaciente, nombrePac, apellidoP, apellidoM, edad, Sexo_idSexo, Ocupacion_idOcupacion, telefono, calleNumero, colonia, cp, ciudad, fecha_crea, fecha_modi) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, now(),null)";
    $query_paciente = $conectar->prepare($sql_paciente);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(1,$nombrePac);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(2,$apellidoP);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(3,$apellidoM);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(4,$edad);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(5,$sexo);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(6,$ocupacion);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(7,$telefono);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(8,$calleNum);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(9,$colonia);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(10,$cp);
    $query_paciente->bindValue(11,$ciudad);
    $query_paciente->execute();

    $sql_dolor = "INSERT INTO dolor (idDolor, Localizacion_idLocalizacion, sintomas) VALUES (NULL, ?, ?)";
    $query_dolor = $conectar->prepare($sql_dolor);
    $query_dolor->bindValue(1,$localizacion);
    $query_dolor->bindValue(2,$sintomas);
    $query_dolor->execute();

    // return

}
```

Para la parte del return no se que necesitas que devulelva la función. Cómo estás ejecutando inserts no tiene mucho sentido hacer un fecthAll(). En este return si es que lo necesitas podrías devolver alguna cosa con sentido en el sitio des de donde llames al metodo insert_paciente, cómo por ejemplo true/false.

Comment: Muchas gracias, si me funciono